# Group numbers if the sum of the numbers in the range is equal to 1

Tags: function, recursion, rust

I have some data like this:

```
[3, 3, 2, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1, None, 1, None]
```

If I assign `1 - x` to each non-None value in the list, or `1` for each None value, I get these numbers:

```
[-2, -2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I assign the numbers from index `i` to `j` to a group if the sum of the numbers in the range is equal to 1, in this case this is what the grouped list looks like:

```
[<-2, <-2, <-1, 1, 1>, 1, 1>, 1, 1>, <0, 1>, <0, 1>]
```

Or if the original numbers are put in:

```
[<3, <3, <2, None, None>, None, None>, None, None>, <1, None>, <1, None>]
```

Each  non-None value is given a score based on how deep it is nested, starting at 0. For example, the `2` in the `<2, None, None>` group has a score of 2. I want to make a function that calculates the score of each number, returning a list of numbers, where each corresponds to the next non-None value in the original list. In the above example, that result would be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Two solutions I could think of:

Create a list of the start and end indices of each group, and for each one, see how many other ranges it falls inside of.

Create a recursive function that calls itself when encountering a non-None value.

An implementation of either of these would be very helpful, otherwise I could use some tips for creating another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use recursion; just use a forward pass with a stack.

- Keep a stack of "open" brackets and how many `None`s are expected.
- When you see a `None`, enter a loop. Each iteration, decrement the end of the array; if it reaches 0 pop it off, otherwise exit the loop.

  - Alternatively, this is equivalent to just popping off all the 1s at the end of the array and then decrementing the end of the array.
- When you see a number, write out the stack depth to the result and add the number to the end of the stack.
- When you get to the end of the input, verify the stack is empty.

[Here's code to do this:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e509fc280b7a826328d7&version=stable)

```
let mut scores = Vec::new();
let mut stack = Vec::new();

for x in data {
    let depth = stack.len();

    if let Some(v) = x {
        scores.push(depth);
        stack.push(v);
    } else {
        while let Some(&1) = stack.last() {
            stack.pop();
        }
        if let Some(last) = stack.last_mut() {
            *last -= 1;
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", scores);
}

assert!(!scores.is_empty());
```